# How to use search_excerpt() function from core search module?

Tags: search

I want to use the function [search_excerpt()](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21search%21search.module/function/search_excerpt/7) to generate excerpts. Unfortunately this function is returning exactly same text as I submit. For example I tried this:

```
$test = (search_excerpt('test', 'this is a test'));
print $test;
```

This is returning "this is a test".

I was expecting more something like:

> "this is a **test**"

What is wrong in my code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this code.I have just added a space after the string and this will surely work

```
$string = 'this is a test';   
$test = (search_excerpt('test', $string.' '));
print $test;
```

In the search_excerpt() if the search text is the last one, then preg_replace omits the search text.In order to overcome this I just added a empty space to the string.

```
// Highlight keywords. Must be done at once to prevent conflicts ('strong' and '<strong>').
  $text = preg_replace('/' . $boundary . '(' . implode('|', $keys) . ')' . $boundary . '/iu', '<strong>\0</strong>', $text);
```

Comment: This definitely works

Answer (score 0):

Normal behaviour for this function, see the documentation: https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!search!search.module/function/search_excerpt/7

Try this code:

```
$test = (search_excerpt('test', 'this is a test'));
print '"'.$test.'"';
```

Comment: That doesn't seem to make any difference - maybe because of the what Ram is indicating in the other answer?